# How to use queryParam?

Tags: angular, service, query-string

Here i have a class project where i need to create a Booksite where there are some info of Books.Now the info of books is to be fetch from a url which is.

```
 myurl  = "http://advjavaapp-env.imadbprai6.us-west- 
2.elasticbeanstalk.com/booksapp/books";
```

Now i have fetch the details..but in Booksite there is a nav bar which has options like Newarrivals,Select Genre(which is dropdown with option Children,Fiction,mystery) and All Books.I have to use queryParam to show the result according to the names.The conditions are

For All Books the URL displayed is /books.Data is fetched from myurl/booksapp/books where myurl is
    http://advjavaapp-env.imadbprai6.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com

Books by Genre is a dropdown with   Fiction, Children,Mystery.The URL displayed is /books/selopt where selopt   is the selected option in the   dropdown.Data is fetched from myurl/booksapp/books/selopt.

For New Arrivals,the URL displayed is /books?newarrival=yes.Data is fetched from myurl/booksapp/books?newarrival=yes

Please help me with this as i am trying doing this from last two days.

work i have done till now..

In Booksdetails.Component.ts

```
myurl   = "http://advjavaapp-env.imadbprai6.us-west- 
 2.elasticbeanstalk.com/booksapp/books";

url: URL[] = [];
showmyurl: URL[] = [];
newarrival: string;
url1: string = this.myurl + '?newarrival' + this.newarrival;

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
  this.newarrival = params[ 'newarrival' ];
   });
}

 new(){
   this.netService.getData(this.url1)
   .subscribe(resp => {
    this.showmyurl = resp;
    })
  }
```

Comment: what is the value you are getting in `showmyurl` object?

Comment: i am not getting anything..i just thought to create a function which will fetch url1..but it is not giving any output..

Comment: in your `myurl` string has no `queryParams`

Comment: can you post your routing paths here please.you are able to get this.newarrival from the params?

Comment: {
      path: 'book',
      component : BooksdetailsComponent
      },
      {
       path: 'home',
        component : HomeComponent
       },
        {
        path: '',
        redirectTo : 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
       },

Comment: @mcsekar  i don't know.Where can i check that??

Comment: move this inside new() function  this.url1= this.myurl + '?newarrival' + this.newarrival;

Comment: Can you post the complete Booksdetails.Component.ts file here please

Comment: i am working in VS Code how can i share my whole project with you..???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190912/discussion-between-mcsekar-and-aman-solanki).

Answer (score 0):

change your code to the below

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {
   console.log(params);
   this.newarrival = params.params[ 'newarrival' ];
  });
}

new(){
 this.url1 = this.myurl + '?newarrival=' + this.newarrival;
 this.netService.getData(this.url1)
 .subscribe(resp => {
  this.showmyurl = resp;
   })
}
```